# Integration of Playwright with Cucumber

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, playwright

I would like to get some expert advice about integration of Playwright with Cucumber.
Why do we use Cucumber.js file instead of Playwright.config.js file to configure the Cucumber feature file and step definition paths ?
**If possible yes**,
How to mention Cucumber feature file and step definition paths in Playwright config file ?
**No**, May I know the reason ?

Thanks & Regards
Parvez Ahamed

Comment: Did the provided answer help solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, Playwright provides only the API to do the interactions and other automation related actions, while Cucumber.js is the tool that allows you to write the tests in the BDD style, through things like step/feature files etc.

By default, when using cucumber.js you will use the cucumber runner to execute the tests, and so will use the cucumber config file, not the playwright.config.js file. You could use an extra plugin such as https://github.com/vitalets/playwright-bdd to achieve that, but natively there is no out of the box way to achieve what you ask.

Playwright.config.js is the options that will dictate how the playwright runner performs its test runs, and therefore is not needed or used when the cucumber runner is in play. As such, you should treat it as a 'either-or' scenario.